# JavaScript function cannot recognise input.checked elment correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my "CheckCheck" function. The following part of the code should generate a to-do task. The input tag dynamically created in JS provides an option to set the priority to the given task. There is an option to set the task to "normal" or "priotity". However, the code sets the fisk task to "on" and after continues with the imposed "priority" and "normal" but inversely. How to prevent this from happening?

The code:

```js
 let tasklist = [];

  function Apply() {

    const Tasktask = document.querySelector(".task-form");
    const Taskdate = document.querySelector(".date");
    const Taskpriority = document.querySelector(".check-box");

    function Prevent() {
      if (Tasktask.value.length === 0 || Taskdate.value === "") {
        alert("Fields cannot be empty!");
      } else {
        Pushed();
        render();
        clear();
      }
    }
    Prevent();

    function Pushed() {
      let newTasks = new Tasks(Tasktask.value, Taskdate.value, Taskpriority.value);
      tasklist.push(newTasks);
      updateLocalStorage();
    }

    function render() {
      CheckCheck();
      insertTd();
    }

    function CheckCheck() {
      if (Taskpriority.checked === true) {
        Taskpriority.value = "priority"
      } else {
        Taskpriority.value = "normal"
      }
    }

    function clear() {
      Tasktask.value = "";
      Taskdate.value = "";
      Taskpriority.checked = false;
    }

    function insertTd() {
      checkLocalStorage();
      const parent2 = document.querySelector(".table-body");
      parent2.innerHTML = "";
      tasklist.forEach((item) => {
        const table = `<tr>
        <td>${item.task}</td>
        <td>${item.date}</td>
        <td>${item.priority}</td>
        <td><a class="delete">delete</a></td>
        </tr>`;
        parent2.insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", table);
      });
    }

    function deleteItem() {
      const Table = document.querySelector("table").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        const currentTarget = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1];
        if (e.target.innerHTML == "delete") {
          if (confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete ${currentTarget.innerText}?`))
            deleteTask(findTask(tasklist, currentTarget.innerText));
        }
        if (e.target.classList.contains("status-button")) {
          findTask(tasklist, currentTarget.innerText);
        }
        updateLocalStorage();
        insertTd();
      });
    }
    deleteItem();

    function deleteTask(currentTask) {
      tasklist.splice(currentTask, currentTask + 1);
    }

    function findTask(taskArray, task) {
      if (taskArray.length === 0 || taskArray === null) {
        return;
      }
      for (let item of taskArray)
        if (item.task === task) {
          return taskArray.indexOf(item);
        }
    }
   }
```

The other thing which is not working as intended is the confirm prompt. The more tasks I add, the more confirm prompts I get. I.e. for 1 task it is only one confirm window, for 3 tasks - 3 windows etc. Why is that?

I also attach below a JSFiddle link how better understanding.
[Link](https://jsfiddle.net/MicSparrow/mcb7hy8p/63/)

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: Taskpriority is an array of check-boxes, so check i the whole array is "checked" doesnt work. What about using forEach?

Comment: @Pauline Nope, the value is created by `querySelector`, that returns a single element.

Comment: My bad, but then it only returns the first element?

Comment: I think you run `Apply` only once and then load the tasks dynamically with Ajax, right?

Comment: I try to do this in pure JS.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't get the state of a checkbox by reading its `value` but its `checked` property. Try `document.querySelector('.check-box').checked`
2. You keep reusing the same buttons and add an event listener to them each time. Either clone them every time, or add the listener once right after creating them.

Simple illustration of the problems here

```js
document.querySelector('#readstates').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const disp  = `Checked\n 1: ${chk1.checked}, 2: ${chk2.checked} \n`
              + `Value\n 1: ${chk1.value}, 2: ${chk2.value}`;
  alert(disp);
});

const spawnBut = document.createElement('button');
spawnBut.id = 'spawned';
spawnBut.textContent = 'Spawned';

document.querySelector('#spawnDirty').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const previous = document.querySelector('form #spawned');
  if (previous) previous.remove();
  
  document.querySelector('#spawnHere').append(spawnBut);
  spawnBut.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('click!');
  });
  
});

document.querySelector('#spawnClone').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const previous = document.querySelector('form #spawned');
  if (previous) previous.remove();
  
  const nSpawnBut = spawnBut.cloneNode(true);
  document.querySelector('#spawnHere').append(nSpawnBut);
  nSpawnBut.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('click!');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<form>
  <p class="inputs">
    <label for="chk1">chk1:</label> <input type="checkbox" id="chk1" />
    <label for="chk2">chk2:</label> <input type="checkbox" id="chk2" value="mycheckedvalue" />
    <button id="readstates">Read chks</button>
  </p>
  <p class="button-spawners">
    Try spamming those then click below:
    <button type="button" id="spawnDirty"
      title="Each time you click this one, the button below is respawned and a new handler is attached">
      Spawn button
    </button>
    <button type="button" id="spawnClone"
      title="This one will spawn a clone each time, so the click handler is attached only once">
      Spawn button clone
    </button>
  </p>
  <p id="spawnHere">
    New button will spawn here
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: sorry typo: I typed "value" instead of "checked" which is exactly what I was warning you about. Corrected now

Comment: Consider changing your display strings to be a single statement using backticks instead of concatenation with escaped newlines, you're already using them in your append statements.

Comment: @JuanMendes my first thought, but it will impose having everything written on a single line, or am I missing something here ?

Comment: @JuanMendes I met you half-way by splitting the statement on 2 lines

Comment: No, you can have newlines within backticks without escaping them.  I will modify it and you can change it back if you don't like it.

Comment: @JuanMendes I know that, but it will break indentation if I use it and make the code a lot harder to read

Comment: @JuanMendes see, exactly what I meant

Comment: Then change it back if you don't like it. It also allows you to use `const`, instead of `let` which is a best practice. I have a really hard time trying to parse newlines in strings but I understand the formatting gets funky

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and taking time to help me!